# Excel sheet insertion not working correctly using fputcsv in php

Tags: php, insert, export-to-csv, fputcsv

I am trying to export into csv file. Here excel sheet insertion not correct. Only 3 rows inserted and it is not only in correct format also (some times 3 rows are inserted to one cell). Please help, what is the reason for that?

$row is a multidimensional array as follows :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => East Midlands
            [2] => East Midlands Equestrian         
        )
   [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => East Midlands
            [2] => Leicester City
       )
)
```

The code used to insert into csv is :-

```
  $fp = fopen('/home/test/workspace/example/sites/default/files/csv/all.csv', 'w');
  $header = array('#', 'Region', 'Club Name', 'Position', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Address 1', 'Address 2', 'City', 'County', 'Post Code', 'Phone', 'Mobile', 'Email', 'Fax');
  fputcsv($fp, $header);
  foreach ($rows as $row) { //$row is 2D array shown above
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
  }
  fclose($fp);
```

Comment: How is the CSV file to be formatted?  Tab or comma delimited?  Are you trying to get 3 columns for each array element?